# Automatic sort multiple columns once entire row of data is entered

Tags: javascript, c++, sorting, computer-science, google-sheets-api

I have designed a google spreadsheet to help improve efficiency of material flow. I want to automatically sort the data by 2 different columns to prioritize critical parts that need to be received first once the entire row of data is entered. The problem I am having is that the data is sorting as soon as you enter one of the columns I am calling to sort but the columns I want to sort are not the last column of that row of data that needs to be entered. I am trying to use an if statement to not execute the sort until the last column has been entered else throw an error statement that says you must enter data in this column to proceed. Logically, the code makes sense to me but I have only an adequate understanding of computer language. I keep receiving an error in line 10 that the range is not found. I believe my error is the syntax in trying to call the last column. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
**function autosort(){
 
 // Variable Declaration
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 var NewsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
 
 var sheetName = sheet.getSheetByName(NewsheetName);
 var lastCol = sheetName.getLastColumn();
 var lastColBlank = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastCol).isBlank()
 // Find range to sort
 var range = sheetName.getRange("A2:G");
 // Sorting algorithm
 if (lastColBlank == false ){
 range.sort([6,5]);
 
 }
 
 else {
 throw ("error: If trailer # is unavailable, please enter N/A");
 
 }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function onEdit() {

 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 2) { 
    var range = sh.getRange("A2:B10");
    var blank = range.isBlank()

    var values = range.getValues();
    Logger.log(values)
    for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
    //values.length returns 11 for eleven items
    // values[10][0] would be the 11th row 1st column
      Logger.log(values[i][1])
    if (values[i][0] ==  "" || values[i][1] ==  "") {
      //throw new Error("error: If trailer # is unavailable, please enter N/A");
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert('If trailer # is unavailable, please enter N/A');
    }else{
      range.sort({column: 2});
    }
  }

  }
}
```

[image]

If you'll look into the code, the sort depends on the second column to be edited. Then, will check the range if the is still a blanked cell.

Just apply your additional code to meet your goal and I think that will work.

Hope this helps.